# Carousel to display full width of screen for small screens only

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have a carousel that is centered and only takes half the screen by adding this to the class "w-50". When the browser resizes to a smaller screen, like a mobile device, I want that carousel to take up the whole width of the screen. To do this I'm sure I'll need to find a way to change that to "w-100", but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

I have tried to play around with @media in CSS, but haven't had any luck.

```
<div id="catalogueSelection">
        <div id="catalogueCarousel" class="carousel slide w-50" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#catalogueCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#catalogueCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#catalogueCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#catalogueCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#catalogueCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
                <li data-target="#catalogueCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                <li data-target="#catalogueCarousel" data-slide-to="6"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img id="franceImage" class="d-block w-100" src="../images/france.jpg">
                    <div class="carousel-caption countryCaption">
                        <h2>France</h2>
                        <p>See Products</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img id="italyImage" class="d-block w-100" src="../images/italy.jpg">
                    <div class="carousel-caption countryCaption">
                        <h2>Italy</h2>
                        <p>See Products</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="../images/spain.jpg">
                    <div class="carousel-caption countryCaption">
                        <h2>Spain</h2>
                        <p>See Products</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img id="lebanonImage" class="d-block w-100" src="../images/lebanon.jpg">
                    <div class="carousel-caption countryCaption">
                        <h2>Lebanon</h2>
                        <p>See Products</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img id="southAfricaImage" class="d-block w-100" src="../images/south_africa.jpg">
                    <div class="carousel-caption countryCaption">
                        <h2>South Africa</h2>
                        <p>See Products</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="southAmericaImage" class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="../images/south_america.jpg">
                    <div class="carousel-caption countryCaption">
                        <h2>South America</h2>
                        <p>See Products</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="domesticImage" class="carousel-item">
                    <img class="d-block w-100" src="../images/united_states.jpg">
                    <div class="carousel-caption countryCaption">
                        <h2>Domestic</h2>
                        <p>See Products</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#catalogueCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#catalogueCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
#catalogueCarousel {
    margin: auto;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-color: black;

}
.carousel-inner {

}
.carousel-item img {
    height: 500px; !important
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.9;   
    opacity: 0.8;       
}
.countryCaption h2 {
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Prosto One', cursive;
    opacity: 1; !important

}
.countryCaption p{
    color: darkred;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Prosto One', cursive;
    font-size: 20px;
    opacity: 1; !important

}
```

Above is a snippet of the carousel html code, as well as it's stylesheet. 
Any tips or ideas to help me resolve this is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a combination of media queries and the `!important` rule.
Assuming `768px` is your mobile breakpoint:

```
@media(max-width:768px){
  #catalogueCarousel {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Alternatavely you could use jQuery:

```
function resizeCarousel() {
  if($window.width() < 768) {
    $('#catalogueCarousel')
      .removeClass('w-50')
      .addClass('w-100');
  } else {
    $('#catalogueCarousel')
      .removeClass('w-100')
      .addClass('w-50');
  }
}
resizeCarousel();
$window.resize(resizeCarousel);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, really like the jQuery method. Appreciate y'all's time!

Answer (score 0):

You just need add media query for small device. Add below CSS in style sheet i hope it'll resolve your issue. Thanks

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #catalogueCarousel {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```